# Manually selecting which Wi-Fi to connect to when all Wi-Fi devices they have the same name and are all open

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I live in a hostel which has very poor management. They have Wi-Fi devices that are all over the hostel all have the same name and no password, and they show as one Wi-Fi on the mobiles and laptops but some of them have good internet speed some don't.

Unfortunately for me my laptop connects to a device that has very very bad internet speed.

#### Is there any way I could manually select a specific Wi-Fi device that I know works well on my Windows 10 laptop?

Map of the routers:

[image: Screenshot.]

My laptop connects to the Wi-Fi router A (which has very bad internet) but I want to connect with Wi-Fi router B (has good internet) but my laptop shows only Wi-Fi router A which has good Wi-Fi strength.

How I can select and connect to Wi-Fi router B?

Comment: I don’t think Windows has the capabilities to connect to a specific _BSSID_. Third-party Wi-Fi management software (like Intel PRO/Set) _might_ help, but I’ve never tried.

Answer (score 5):

Try a third-party utility, such as Nirsoft's free [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html), shown below,which shows the *MAC Address*, as well as SSID (name) for each connection, the average signal quality, bandwidth, etc. By right-clicking on a device, you can connect immediately, or even create a desktop shortcut so that you can use to reestablish the connection later!

BTW, I find after hibernation, Windows sometimes forgets to reconnect, and that desktop shortcut is helpful to get WiFi working again.

[image: WiFi Info View]