# Wifi card limits download speed before router restart

Tags: windows, router, laptop, internet, network-adapter

I'm having weird problem, when laptop boots, download speed on it is limited to just **0,6MB/s**. Once router gets restarted and laptop is on, speed returns to normal. I'm guessing that problem must be in card/os as I'm not having problems with any other device. I'm not really able to currently connect laptop to network via cable, so **WIFI** is only option. Laptop is set to performance mode and plugged in to power outlet (to not drop performance).

**WIFI card:** *Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter*

**OS:** *Windows 11* (problem was exisiting on *Win10* before update)

**Router:** *Alcatel HUB71*

I've checked many things on internet but didn't find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happen to upload and download speed? Do you have any other OS in that machine (for example, for performing the same test from a Linux live system)?

Comment: Update the firmware in the Router.

Comment: @golimar that's only OS and this happens to download speed only

Comment: @John drivers of card and firmware of router are all up to date

Comment: In that case, you may need to asl your ISP

Comment: It affects only download of 1 device until restart, don't really get how could it be problem with router tho

Comment: I don't know (I have many devices on my own router - no issue).  Incompatible device?

Comment: Laptop was bought like 2,5 years ago, router was changed last year with ISP contract change, so they should be compatible

Comment: I don’t know. This is one of those “nothing is wrong “ but it doesn’t work questions.  Try a different router.

Comment: Your PC might be using a low-speed channel until router restarts. Try a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's WiFi Info View to see channel and speed. You can also use that tool to make a desktop shortcut to a particular WiFi SSID. See https://superuser.com/questions/1744171/manually-selecting-which-wi-fi-to-connect-to-when-all-wi-fi-devices-they-have-th/1744186#1744186